# Why is counting using AND/OR, IN(), and two separate queries added up together returning different results? in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm a bit confused with the results of the following queries, why are they returning different results?
What's the difference between AND/OR and IN()?

**Example #1:**

Using two separate queries added together:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users 
WHERE test_1= 1 
AND id IN (
    SELECT user_id FROM items
        WHERE data_type = 'import_test_1'
        AND is_active = 1
);
```

The above code returns 949

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users 
WHERE test_1= 1 
AND id IN (
    SELECT user_id FROM items
        WHERE data_type = 'import_test_2'
        AND is_active = 1
);
```

The above code returns 148

Both combined: **949 + 148 = 1097**

**Example #2:**

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users 
    WHERE test_1= 1 
    AND id IN (
        SELECT user_id FROM items
            WHERE data_type IN ('import_test_1', 'import_test_2')
            AND is_active = 1
    );
```

The above code returns: **1073**

**Example #3:**

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users 
    WHERE test_1= 1 
    AND id IN (
        SELECT user_id FROM items
            WHERE data_type = 'import_test_1' 
            OR data_type = 'import_test_2'
            AND is_active = 1
    );
```

The above code returns: **1089**

Example #1: 1097
Example #2: 1073
Example #3: 1089

Shouldn't Example #1,#2, and #3 return the same results? What's difference of using IN, AND/OR, and doing it as a 2 separate queries and adding the results afterwards?

Sorry if this is badly explained, let me know if you need more information.

Comment: The first query double counts users. The last query has a broken where clause with `and`/`or` without bracketing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they should not.

**Example1** will return two rows for each User that has both import_test_1 and import_test_2

**Example2** will get rid of the duplicates from Example1 - this is probably what you want.

**Example3** is a wonderful example on why you should **always** put parentheses around your boolean expressions to avoid nasty surprises - this

```
WHERE data_type = 'import_test_1' 
            OR data_type = 'import_test_2'
            AND is_active = 1
```

is equivalent to

```
WHERE data_type = 'import_test_1' 
            OR (data_type = 'import_test_2'
            AND is_active = 1)
```

and *not* equivalent to

```
WHERE (data_type = 'import_test_1' 
            OR data_type = 'import_test_2')
            AND is_active = 1
```

which should return the same results as Example2.

Comment: Thank you very much! That explained it :). Have to wait 1 minute to mark this as answered.

Answer (score 1):

Not at all.  For the first two, you are missing the fact that some users have both items.  You are counting *users* not user/item pairs.

The third *should* return the same as the second, but you have a syntax "error".  Your `where` clause is interpreted as:

```
        WHERE (data_type = 'import_test_1') OR
              (data_type = 'import_test_2' AND is_active = 1)
```

But you really mean:

```
        WHERE (data_type = 'import_test_1' OR data_type = 'import_test_2') AND
              is_active = 1
```

So the third is counting not-active items in some cases.

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer helped a lot, I wish I could mark both as the answer.

Comment: @TimothyOnggowasito . . . Oh, that happens.  And Frank was 2 seconds faster than me anyway.